# Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings, : line 1 did not have 2 elements

Tags: r

```
examdata <- RCurl::getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jrwolf/IT497/master/spendingdata.txt")

examdata2 <- read.table(textConnection(examdata), sep = ",", header = T)
```

> Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines,
>   na.strings,  :    line 1 did not have 2 elements

Comment: Try `examdata2 <- read.table(textConnection(examdata), sep = ",", header = TRUE, skip=31, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: Why did you delete the URL? It's important to the answer to the question

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you just need to skip a few lines.  I used `readLines(textConnection(examdata))` to determine where the actual data table began.  Turns out it starts on the 32nd line.  Therefore we can use the `skip` argument in `read.csv` to skip the first 31 lines. I used the `strip.white` argument because there seems to be some erroneous whitespace in the table.

```
(df <- read.csv(text = examdata, skip = 31L, strip.white = TRUE))
#                          Type Cash Check Credit Debit Electronic Other Total
# 1 Average Number of Purchases 23.7   3.9   10.1  14.4        4.4   2.3  58.7
# 2   Average Transaction Value  $21  $168    $56   $44       $216   $69   $59
# 3      Value of Payments in %   14    19     16    18         27     5   100
```

Since you'll probably want those numbers to be numeric, you'll need to remove the `$` sign and convert the columns to numeric so you'll be able to use them for any calculations you may do later.

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) as.numeric(sub("[$]", "", x)))
df
#                          Type Cash Check Credit Debit Electronic Other Total
# 1 Average Number of Purchases 23.7   3.9   10.1  14.4        4.4   2.3  58.7
# 2   Average Transaction Value 21.0 168.0   56.0  44.0      216.0  69.0  59.0
# 3      Value of Payments in % 14.0  19.0   16.0  18.0       27.0   5.0 100.0
```

Now all the columns except the first are numeric.

Comment: thanks for the help.....you simply gave me the answer.....you could have explained the stuff too.

Comment: Well you could have put some words in your post instead of just dumping your code that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

`read.table` and `read.csv` will take a URL as a path and handle the connection for you, so you don't really need `RCurl`:

```
read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jrwolf/IT497/master/spendingdata.txt", 
         skip = 31)

##                          Type Cash Check Credit Debit Electronic Other Total
## 1 Average Number of Purchases 23.7   3.9   10.1  14.4        4.4   2.3  58.7
## 2   Average Transaction Value  $21  $168    $56   $44       $216   $69   $59
```

Further, if you use `readr::read_csv`, you can tell it to parse columns to numbers, stripping out `$` characters as it reads:

```
library(readr)

read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jrwolf/IT497/master/spendingdata.txt", 
         skip = 31, 
         col_types = cols(Type = 'c', .default = 'n'))    # c = character, n = number

## # A tibble: 2 × 8
##                          Type  Cash Check Credit Debit Electronic Other Total
##                         <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1 Average Number of Purchases  23.7   3.9   10.1  14.4        4.4   2.3  58.7
## 2   Average Transaction Value  21.0 168.0   56.0  44.0      216.0  69.0  59.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df <- read.csv("x.csv",... ,**quote = "", fill=TRUE**)
```